# Custom Header for Magento

Tags: html, css, magento

I am very new to Magento. I designed a theme using HTML and CSS. I would like to add my custom header in the magento. What would be the procedure to be followed?

Can anyone tell me the step-by-step procedures for integrating header/footer and main content in the magento ?

Looking for a fruitful reply

Thanks

Teekeybee

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TeeKeyBee | Demo Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
          <header class="header-container">
            <img src="img/logo.png"/>
            <div class="row top-links">
              <div class="span8"></div>
              <div class="span2 borderr">Register | Login</div>
              <div class="span2">Cart 0 &euro; 0.00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-menu">
              <div class="span2"><img src="img/side_logo.png"/></div>
              <div class="span10">Home | About Us | Services | Gallery | Contact Us</div>
            </div>

          </header>


      </div>

    </div><!-- End Container -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.header-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
    background: #000;
}

.top-links {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #b6b6b6;
    margin: 0 auto;
}



.borderr {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
}
```

Comment: Please add your Magento version. See http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy

Comment: Please add a link to your downloaded theme too.

Comment: the theme is not downloaded ....It was created by me.

Comment: sorry, i misread "designed" as "downloaded".

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to create a Boostraped Magento Theme? In order to save your self A LOT of work you should just override the header and footer templates. Since I don't know what you've done, here are the steps from the beginning:

1. Create template and skin folders: Since your using CE youd want to put these in:
   app/design/frontend/default/your_theme and skin/frontend/default/your_theme
2. Change setting in admin to point to your new theme: Ths is done in the admin in System > Configuration > General > Design > Theme. Change these values to "your_theme"
3. Add css files to theme via layout xml: in app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/layout/local.xml

   > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0"?>
   >
   > <layout version="0.1.0">
   >     <default>
   >         <reference name="head">
   >             <action method="addItem">
   >                 <type>skin_js</type>
   >                 <script>js/jquery.js</script>
   >             </action>
   >             <action method="addItem">
   >                 <type>skin_js</type>
   >                 <script>js/bootstrap.min.js</script>
   >             </action>
   >             <action method="addItem">
   >                 <type>skin_css</type>
   >                 <name>css/bootstrap.css</name>
   >             </action>
   >             <action method="addItem">
   >                 <type>skin_css</type>
   >                 <name>css/custom.css</name>
   >             </action>
   >         </reference>
   >       </default>
   > </layout>
   > ```

   css files go in skin/frontend/default/your_theme/css/

   js files go in skin/frontend/default/your_theme/js/
4. Override header.phtml: Copy app/design/frontend/default/default/template/page/html/header.phtml to app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/page/html/. You'll notice that this template looks nothing like header you have.  Again, you'll save your self alot of work by using what's there and manipulating it.

There's a lot manipulation of other templates to do what you're asking. But this will at least get you started.